# Java: Easier pretty printing?

Tags: java, console, pretty-print

At the end of my computations, I print results:

```
System.out.println("\nTree\t\tOdds of being by the sought author");

for (ParseTree pt : testTrees) {
 conditionalProbs = reg.classify(pt.features());

 System.out.printf("%s\t\t%f", pt.toString(), conditionalProbs[1]);
 System.out.println();
}
```

This produces, for instance:

```
Tree  Odds of being by the sought author
K and Burstner  0.000000
how is babby formed answer  0.005170
Mary is in heat  0.999988
Prelim  1.000000
```

Just putting two `\t` in there is sort of clumsy - the columns don't really line up. I'd rather have an output like this:

```
Tree                         Odds of being by the sought author
K and Burstner               0.000000
how is babby formed answer   0.005170
Mary is in heat              0.999988
Prelim                       1.000000
```

(note: I'm having trouble making the SO text editor line up those columns perfectly, but hopefully you get the idea.)

Is there an easy way to do this, or must I write a method to try to figure it out based on the length of the string in the "Tree" column?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for field lengths. Try using this:

```
printf ("%-32s %f\n", pt.toString(), conditionalProbs[1])
```

The -32 tells you that the string should be left justified, but with a field length of 32 characters (adjust to your liking, I picked 32 as it is a multiple of 8, which is a normal tab stop on a terminal). Using the same on the header, but with `%s` instead of `%f` will make that one line up nicely too.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is the amazing yet free `format()`.

It works by letting you specify placeholders in a template string; it produces a combination of template and values as output.

Example:

```
System.out.format("%-25s %9.7f%n", "K and Burstner", 0.055170);
```

- `%s` is a placeholder for Strings;
- `%25s` means blank-pad any given String to 25 characters.
- `%-25s` means left-justify the String in the field, i.e. pad to the right of the string.
- `%9.7f` means output a floating-point number with 9 places in all and 7 to the right of the decimal.
- `%n` is necessary to "do" a line termination, which is what you're otherwise missing when you go from `System.out.println()` to `System.out.format()`.

Alternatively, you can use

```
String outputString = String.format("format-string", arg1, arg2...);
```

to create an output String, and then use

```
System.out.println(outputString);
```

as before to print it.

Comment: misstplaced the `\n` in the format string `%9.7\nf`... and could use `%n`  like in `"%-25s %9.7f%n"`.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
System.out.printf("%-30s %f\n", pt.toString(), conditionalProbs[1]);
```

See the docs for [more information on the Formatter mini-language](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Answer (score 1):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Using [j-text-utils](https://code.google.com/p/j-text-utils/) you may print to console a table like:
[image]

And it as simple as:

```
TextTable tt = new TextTable(columnNames, data);                                                         
tt.printTable();
```

The API also allows sorting and row numbering ...

Comment: Looks nice.  Some of us still have to generate reports without HTML :)

Comment: @Daniel_or_else you may want to edit your link: https://github.com/mkotyk/j-text-utils. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `java.io.PrintStream`'s [`printf`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) and/or [`format`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method is what you are looking for...